# Github - Why would HTTPS stop working while SSH works fine

Tags: git, github, ssh

With no changes on my system over a weekend, on Monday I was no longer able to pull from an organizations github repos; other github repos worked fine. This was the message I got:

```
$ git pull
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myorg/repo2.git/' not found
```

Another befuddling thing is that the same repos in the org worked fine from the github web interface.

I googled for answers and followed the directions for adding a new ssh key to my github profile. I then tried this command and it passed; previous to adding the new key, it failed:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
```

Since I could now pass the login test, but still could not pull the remote repo. I was forced to change the origin url to use ssh.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com/user/repo2.git
# Change the 'origin' remote's URL
```

The updated url works now, but why is the https url broken?

I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First, passing the `ssh -T` test means that you *have* to use an ssh url anyway. It doesn't solve anything regarding the https one.

Second, a repo "not found" doesn't always mean that the repo doesn't exist anymore, but that it isn't accessible by your account.

It is possible that the composition of the [teams defined in the organization](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations) has changed, and that your account is no longer part of the team allowed to modified that repo (as opposed to declare an ssh key directly within that repo admin panel).

Comment: The ssh command is given in the github docs to test your access. The reason I note it here is that is shows I have access, first to github and second to the repo using ssh. The oddity here is that https still fails to work from the command line, but the web interface works as expected. I'm assuming the web interface uses http/https.

Comment: @Mondain the web interface should be able to display the exact url it uses, no?

Comment: I'm not aware of how to find out what they use internal to the their web app. The repo urls are however selectable on the page for clone operations.

Comment: @Mondain one way would be to revert to the command line, go to the root folder of the repo, and type "`git remote -v`"

Comment: That just shows the remote push/fetch urls, which I've already switched over to use ssh (noted in the question above).